# MySQL Grant Permission

Tags: mysql, permissions

I want to Grant a user only **INSERT** permission.

When I try to insert data, it throws the error "Access Denied".

What permission do I give a user to use/select database in mysql and how?

I have given only `GRANT INSERT ON database.* To user@'localhost';`

Comment: Is this just a straight insert or an insert on duplicate key update?

Answer (score 1):

'insert' permission should be all you need to do an `insert`:

```
create database stack;
create user dummy;
create table stack.t(v integer primary key);
grant insert on stack.* to dummy;
```

as dummy:

```
insert into stack.t values(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

select * from stack.t;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'dummy'@'localhost' for table 't'
```

and the `grant` like this will even apply to tables created after the `grant` was made - it gives a [database privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges)

As you also want to `select` you will also need to `grant`**`select`**`on stack.* to dummy`

Comment: Seems good to me, +1 !!!